# Не отображается ProgressBar Android

Tags: java, android, java-ee, progress-bar

При разработке в основном тестировал на Android 7.1, когда же дошло до Lolipop и ниже перестал отображаться ProgressBar в одной из Activity (Хотя в других работает).

```
public static void getNextElements(){
    if(Engine.hasInternetConnection(fa)){
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter = new ExAdapter(Engine.getNextListOfEx(mReference), fa);
                rec.setAdapter(adapter);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                raw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }else{
        reload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        raw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Это код одного из потоков, в нём подгружается информация из Базы Данных и **скрывается** progressBar (переменная progress).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/art_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Это код progressBar'а

А здесь скрины:
[image: Это на старом Андроиде][image: Это на новом Андроиде]

Comment: Попробуйте progressBar-y выставить атрибут android:translationZ="2dp"

Comment: добавь в RelativeLayout атрибут background = black. Думаю ты уже понял причину